# IBM MQ limitations

Tags: ibm-mq

> As I am evaluating IBM MQ, I am looking for some technical details on its strengths and limitations.

1. Maximum number of connections
2. How much high volume it can support
3. Maximum size of the message it supports
4. How do I redoif message was lost due to client was offline? Examples?
5. How do I apply transactions in the messages? Examples?
6. Are there any examples to send / subscribe messages directly from
   mobile device?
7. What are the strong features IBM MQ provides which are not available
   in other competitive JMS products (ex: Weblogic, Rabitt MQ, etc) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like your boss asked you to do some research on MQ but instead you posted the questions here.  Did you read any of the IBM RedBooks on MQ?  Here is the [MQ Primer](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp0021.html?Open) which is a good starting point for beginners.  Did you read the [MQ Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q002610_.htm)?

You still need to do more research unless you want to hire me as a consultant (I'm not cheap!!) but here are some answers off the top of my head.

1. Depends on the horsepower of the server.  Years ago, I've had queue managers handling thousands and thousands of connections without issue.
2. Again it depends on the horsepower of the server.  On the mainframe, I know of customer moving hundreds of millions of messages per day without issue.
3. Come on, that is the easiest thing to look up in MQ.  (default is 4MB - max is 100MB otherwise use message grouping)
4. Pub/Sub or Point-to-Point?  For Pub/Sub use durable subscription and for P-2-P use persistent messages.  Besides, MQ does NOT loose messages if the client application is not connected.  It would be a pretty bad messaging system if it did - maybe you're using a bad one right now.
5. You can have local UOW or 2 Phase UOW.
6. Sure. Install MQ and select Samples then go and play around with the samples.  Did you do any internet searches?  The [MQ Telemetry Transport (MQTT) Programming](http://mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2013/MQ_Telemetry_Transport_Programming.pdf) presentation should have been at the top. Note: There are more presentations on MQTT at [MQTC](http://mqtechconference.com/)'s web site.  You can also find lots of MQ samples [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_sample_code.html).
7. Ask your IBM sales rep.